# Acura MDX rear-seat cup holder not opening

Tags: interior, acura

I have an Acura MDX 2008, and I recently noticed that the rear seat cup holder was broken. It won't open up. As I don't have a warranty on the vehicle, how can I fix this issue? Thanks!

[image: An image of the cup holder]

Comment: Is it part of the center console? you may be able to take it apart. or push really hard to see if it will release. or put a plastic prying tool in there see if you can pull it out.

Comment: I believe it is part of the console. Which of those methods would be most practical in this case?

Comment: probably pushing if you have some sort of cleaner try spraying it around where you think the latch is maybe something sticky spilled in there.